# How do you find words in a text file and print the most frequent word shown using array?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble of figuring out how to find the most frequent word and the most frequent case-insensitive word for a program. I have a scanner that reads through the text file and a while loop, but still doesn't know how to implement what I'm trying to find. Do I use a different string function to read and print the word out?

Here is my code as of now:

```
public class letters {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
    String word[] = new String[500];
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = scanner.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
             }

          }
      String []roll = s.split("\\s");
       for(int i=0;i<roll.length;i++){
           String lin = roll[i];
           //System.out.println(lin);
      }
 }
```

This is what I have so far. I need the output to say:

```
   Word:
   6 roll

  Case-insensitive word:
  18 roll
```

And here is my input file:

```
@
roll tide roll!
Roll Tide Roll!
ROLL TIDE ROLL!
ROll tIDE ROll!
 roll  tide  roll! 
 Roll  Tide  Roll! 
 ROLL  TIDE  ROLL! 
   roll    tide    roll!   
    Roll Tide Roll  !   
@
65-43+21= 43
65.0-43.0+21.0= 43.0
 65 -43 +21 = 43 
 65.0 -43.0 +21.0 = 43.0 
 65 - 43 + 21 = 43 
 65.00 - 43.0 + 21.000 = +0043.0000 
    65   -  43  +   21  =   43
```

I just need it to find the most occuring word(Which is the maximal consecutive sequence of letters)(which is roll) and print out how many times it is located(which is 6) . If anybody can help me on this, that would be really great! thanks

Answer (score 5):

Consider using a `Map<String,Integer>` for the word then you can implement this to count words and will be work for any number of words. [See Documentation for Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Like this (would require modification for case insensitive)

```
public Map<String,Integer> words_count = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

//read your line (you will have to determine if this line should be split or is equations
//also just noticed that the trailing '!' would need to be removed

String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
{
     String s = words[i];
     if(words_count.ketSet().contains(s))
     {
          Integer count = words_count.get(s) + 1;
          words_count.put(s, count)
     }
     else
          words_count.put(s, 1)

}
```

Then you have the number of occurrences for each word in the string and to get the most occurring do something like

```
Integer frequency = null;
String mostFrequent = null;
for(String s : words_count.ketSet())
{
    Integer i = words_count.get(s);
    if(frequency == null)
         frequency = i;
    if(i > frequency)
    {
         frequency = i;
         mostFrequent = s;
    }
}
```

Then to print

```
System.out.println("The word "+ mostFrequent +" occurred "+ frequency +" times");
```

Comment: I thought "space" was "\\s+" rather than "\\s".

Comment: `\\s+` just means one or more spaces

Comment: I've never worked with Hashmap before. I'm going to have to look it up. but thanks though!

Comment: and how would you write that for the System.out.println() outcome.

Comment: I've been trying to put your code in, but the words_count keeps giving me errors. I don't think I'm allowed to use HashMaps on this program also. I'm only allowed to use arrays and strings.

Comment: What errors? and why would you not be allowed to use HashMaps, make sure you include the appropriate import statements.

Answer (score 1):

Start with accumulating all the words into a Map as follows:

```
...
String[] roll = s.split("\\s+");
for (final String word : roll) {
    Integer qty = words.get(word);
    if (qty == null) {
        qty = 1;
    } else {
        qty = qty + 1;
    }
    words.put(word, qty);
}
...
```

Then you need to figure out which has the biggest score:

```
String bestWord;
int maxQty = 0;
for(final String word : words.keySet()) {
    if(words.get(word) > maxQty) {
        maxQty = words.get(word);
        bestWord = word;
    }
}
System.out.println("Word:");
System.out.println(Integer.toString(maxQty) + " " + bestWord);
```

And last you need to merge all forms of the same word together:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordsNoCase = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(final String word : words.keySet()) {
    Integer qty = wordsNoCase.get(word.toLowerCase());
    if(qty == null) {
        qty = words.get(word);
    } else {
        qty += words.get(word);
    }
    wordsNoCase.put(word.toLowerCase(), qty);
}
words = wordsNoCase;
```

Then re-run the previous code snippet to find the word with the biggest score.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this without the use of Hashmap?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use HashMap for better results. You need to use `BufferedReader` and `Filereader` for taking input file as follows:

```
FileReader text = new FileReader("file.txt");
BufferedReader textFile = new BufferedReader(text);
```

The `Bufferedreader` object `textfile` needs to passed as a parameter to the method below:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> countWordFrequency(BufferedReader textFile) throws IOException
{
/*This method finds the frequency of words in a text file
 * and saves the word and its corresponding frequency in 
 * a HashMap.
 */
    HashMap<String, Integer> mapper = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    StringBuffer multiLine = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = null;
    if(textFile.ready())
    {
        while((line = textFile.readLine()) != null)
        {
            multiLine.append(line);
            String[] words = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase().split(" ");
            for(String word : words)
            {
                if(!word.isEmpty())
                {
                    Integer freq = mapper.get(word);
                    if(freq == null)
                    {
                        mapper.put(word, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mapper.put(word, freq+1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        textFile.close();
    }
    return mapper;
}
```

The line `line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase().split(" ");` is used for replacing all the characters other than alphabets, the it makes all the words in lower case (which solves your case insensitive problem) and then splits the words seperated by spaces.

```
/*This method finds the highest value in HashMap
 * and returns the same.
 */
public int maxFrequency(HashMap<String, Integer> mapper)
{
    int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int value : mapper.values())
    {
        if(value > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = value;
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

The above code returns that value in hashmap which is highest.

```
/*This method prints the HashMap Key with a particular Value.
 */
public void printWithValue(HashMap<String, Integer> mapper, Integer value)
{
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : mapper.entrySet()) 
    {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) 
        {
            System.out.println("Word : " + entry.getKey() + " \nFrequency : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can print the most frequent word along with its frequency as above.

Answer (score -2):

```
    /*  i have declared LinkedHashMap containing String as a key and occurrences as  a value.
     * Creating BufferedReader object
     * Reading the first line into currentLine
     * Declere while-loop & splitting the currentLine into words
     * iterated using for loop. Inside for loop, i have an if else statement
     * If word is present in Map increment it's count by 1 else set to 1 as value
     * Reading next line into currentLine
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:\\chidanand\\javaIO\\Student.txt"));
              String currentLine = reader.readLine();
            while (currentLine!= null) {
                String[] input = currentLine.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase().split(" ");
                  for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                    if (map.containsKey(input[i])) {
                        int count = map.get(input[i]);
                        map.put(input[i], count + 1);

                    } else {
                        map.put(input[i], 1);
                    }

                }
                   currentLine = reader.readLine();
            }

            String mostRepeatedWord = null;
             int count = 0;
                 for (Entry<String, Integer> m:map.entrySet())
                    {
                        if(m.getValue() > count)
                        {
                           mostRepeatedWord = m.getKey();

                            count = m.getValue();
                        }
                    }

                 System.out.println("The most repeated word in input file is : "+mostRepeatedWord);

                    System.out.println("Number Of Occurrences : "+count);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```